# Chart.js adds second lines values to first

Tags: javascript, charts

I have bar/line chart on my page and there is two lines and four bar values. 
The first line is average value, that is one straight line, so it is array that filled with same number. Second line has different values that are not related to first line number. The think is that the first line raises the second line?? When I click to enable the average line, then the second line goes to right place. Is this a bug or did I do something wrong? 
Here is is the code:

```
  var ctx_bar = document.getElementById("points").getContext('2d');
var average = Array.apply(null, Array(points_order[0].length)).map(Number.prototype.valueOf,glob_pisteet[4][3]);
trows_chart = new Chart(ctx_bar, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: points_order[4],
        datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            label: 'average',
            borderColor: 'rgb(50, 50, 0)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            fill: false,
            radius: 0,
            data: average
        },{
            type: 'line',
            label: 'points/trow',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 51, 51)',
            borderWidth: 4,
            fill: false,
            data: points_order[5]
        },{
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'first',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(0, 92, 230)',
            stack: 'round 1',
            data: points_order[0]
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'second',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(102, 163, 255)',
            stack: 'round 1',
            data: points_order[1]
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'third',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(230, 138, 0)',
            stack: 'round 2',
            data: points_order[2]
        }, {
            type: 'bar',
            label: 'fourth',
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 194, 102)',
            stack: 'round 2',
            data: points_order[3]
        }]

    },
    options: {
                title:{
                    display:true,
                    text:"Drows"
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
                        stacked: true,
                    }],
                    yAxes: [{
                        stacked: true
                    }]
                }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the reason:

If you have your options setting like this:

```
          title:{
              display:true,
              text:"Heitot"
          },
          tooltips: {
              mode: 'index',
              intersect: false
          },
          responsive: true,
          scales: {
              xAxes: [{
                  stacked: true,
              }],
              yAxes: [{
                  stacked: true
              }]
          }
```

Then it will do that. As soon as you take this part:

```
          yAxes: [{
              stacked: true
          }]
```

away or change stacked: true to false, then it acts like normal.